# What the best way to connect Flash with Java?

Tags: java, flash

It`s not a secret that is very difficult to create beauty user interface using Java. Flash has powerful tools for it. We use Flash to show some nice face and Java to process business logic(DB, calculation etc). How they can connect (over HTTP or TCP/IP not important) without additional technologies?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Flex, its remote function call API binds directly to Java classes and communicates over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Flex, not Flash for user-interfaces. Flex is much more suitable for this kind of applications, and has many built-in features for data-communications.

More on the combination Flex- Java can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_java.html

Comment: Thanx, and what about game with some business logic? I think Flash is more convenient for it. Mb I am wrong.

Comment: Flex is just a Flash framework. It's built on top of Flash, so you can still build game elements into it. Flex just makes doing a lot of stuff much easier.

Answer (score 0):

why not use [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/)?

Comment: Users have to install jre to see javafx sites. You can search for some statistics about percentage of users with already installed jre but I guess it's less then 50%.